# How do I input folder names by address in Debian Wheezy 7?

Tags: linux, debian

In an older version of Debian I was able to click a button on the left side of the address bar in the folder browser and switch from the poorly designed buttons to being able to input an address, like `/etc/blah/blah/blah`

In Debian Wheezy 7 I don't understand how to change back to this format from the default format of clicking on a button of each folder, and I can't find the option to change it.

Where do I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open Nautilus
2. Press on the "Go" menu item
3. Press on the "Location" menu subitem
4. Input your location(directory)
5. Bonus, you can use ctrl + L as a shortcut

Comment: @user2056201 you should press the button to accept the answer, if the answer is satisfiable.